# Timing Diagram question

Tags: flipflop, timing, diagram

Can anyone check my timing diagram for me? I have my exam tomorrow and just want to make sure I am understanding these correctly:

[image]

Any feedback is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When CLK first goes high, A is high and B is low, so the first flip-flop is set, and C goes high as you indicate.  In your diagram, you show C going high slightly before the CLK goes high, this is just sloppy; it will actually go high a bit later due to whatever propagation delay there is in the flip-flop.  (I assume you should be taking these into consideration.)

You then assume the second flip-flop will also be set, because A · C would be high, and in fact show D going high at the same time C does in the diagram.  But again you are forgetting about propagation delays; by the time A · C goes high there have now been two propagation delays (first the flip-flop, and second, the AND gate), so the rising edge of the CLK has already passed and nothing will happen at the second flip-flop (D will stay low).

I'm not going to continue and correct the rest of the diagram for you; next time take more care in drawing it so the cause and effect of each signal is clearly shown.

Comment: Its not a picture that I'm going to frame and hang on the wall it is just a quick sketch to check If I am going about this correctly.  I'm new to this so just settle down a little bit but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @user2989591 I was just trying to point out that in doing timing diagrams, it is important to show the relationship between transitions (edges), and if C is the result of the CLK rising, but C appears before the rising of the CLK in the diagram this makes no sense.  For a more formal way of looking at this (with the cause and effects more clearly shown), refer to [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96917/how-to-draw-a-timing-diagram-for-a-logic-circuit/96958#96958).  p.s. I've been doing this for 45 years, yes that's not a typo, so I've had a little practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram isn't clear. Assuming ideal case (e.g zero setup and hold time) & input changes during clock edges: On 2nd rising clock edge, output C should go down to 0. Because at this point, 1st JK flipflop has J=0,K=1 that is reset condition.

Same thing happens for output D for this case.

Btw, why don't you try simulate this with some tool?

Comment: Before the second rise J is 1 and K is 0 so I believe C stays as it is.

Comment: well, i'm considering the ideal case. otherwise, your input doesn't even meet the setup constraint and It would go to metastable state.